# How can i fetch data in a foreach() loop in Laravel controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a one-to-many relationship between group and students and I want to get all students of some groups so I do this:

```
public function getStudentsOfGroups()
{
    $groups = Auth::user()->groups;
    foreach($groups as $group){
        $students  = $group->students;
    }

    return view('teacher.home', compact('students'));
}
```

but it doesn't get the data I need, so what can I do instead?

Comment: `$students[]  = $group->students;` otherwise you will only see the data from the last iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$students = Student::whereHas('groups', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('your_foreign_key_on_groups', auth()->id());
})
->get();
```

---

**NOTE:** When you want to add something to an array, you should use this syntax:

```php
$array[] = 'a new element';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function getStudentsOfGroups()
{
    $groups = Auth::user()->groups;
    foreach($groups as $group){
        $students[]  = $group->students;
    }

    return view('teacher.home', compact('students'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, please consider adding more details as to how this helps solve the question. The more detail you can add the more helpful your answer will be to other's. Please consider reviewing the how to answer article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$results = Auth::user()->groups->students
```

Or

```
$results = Group::with('students')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id;
```